# React Native error: "Don't hotlink internal Babel files."

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I just upgraded to react native 0.6.0 and I'm getting this error.

> /Users/Tom/Desktop/AppProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/tools/protect.js:15
>       throw new Error("Don't hotlink internal Babel files.");

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post code from your react project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please update `babel` to latest version `v5.6.10`, or use a old version, for example `v5.6.5`.

`v5.6.10` fixes faulty internal require check.
https://github.com/babel/babel/compare/v5.6.9...v5.6.10

Comment: How do I upgrade babel in react native?

Comment: the easist way, it should just uninstall react native, then install.. it should be some file like `package.json`, or `node_modules`, you can use `npm install babel@5.6.10` to update. I'll check react native later.

Comment: navigate to `<project>/node_modules/react-native`, then run `npm install babel@5.6.10 --save`, it should fixed. ... And, the latest version is `5.6.11` now....I hate the babel, stupid release.